# Ruby API response view : how can I render a JSON response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api

I'm new to Ruby, trying to building an API.

I've followed a tutorial and was able to return a JSON response when calling an API endpoint.

In this example, the function called raises an error that I want to pass as a JSON response.

## my_controller.rb

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def getTracklist

    begin
      importer = #this raises an error
    rescue StandardError => e
      @response = {
      error:  e.message,
      }
      return @response
    end

  end

end
```

my view look like this :

## getTracklist.json.jbuilder

```
json.response @response
```

## thing is,

this works but renders my response as

```
{"response":{"error":"the error message"}}
```

while I want it as

```
{"error":"the error message"}
```

I made an attempts by changing my view to

```
json @response
```

but it fails :

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `json' for
>   <#:0x0000559304675470> Did you mean?  JSON):
>       1: json @response

**So how could I render my response "fully" without having to put it in a property ?**

I've also seen when reading stuff about ROR that this code is sometimes used, and I was wondering how I could use it in this situation :

```
render json: { error_code:'not_found', error: e.message }, status: :not_found
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of achieving what you want. You could [`merge!`](https://rubydoc.info/gems/jbuilder/Jbuilder#merge!-instance_method) the response into the jbuilder root.

```
json.merge! @response
```

The above merges all key/value-pairs into the jbuilder root. You could also opt to [`extract!`](https://rubydoc.info/gems/jbuilder/Jbuilder#extract!-instance_method) specific attributes.

```
json.extract! @response, :error
```

Alternatively you can simply render it in the controller, since you've already composed the structure the following would be enough.

```
render json: @response
```

Comment: most complete response even if the others were right. Thanks, no view = better !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for jBuilder:

```
json.merge!(@response)
```

[Source](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/jbuilder/Jbuilder:merge!)

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def getTracklist

    begin
     # you need to assign something to a variable
    rescue StandardError => e
      respond_to do |format|
        format.any(:json, :js) do
          render :json => {:error => e.message}
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Making these changes to your controller can help you with your requirements.
You don't need a view after doing this.